# beamer: Text indentation within blocks

Tags: beamer, formatting, indentation, block

I want text indentation within blocks. My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% For global Justification
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt plus 0cm}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}


\begin{document}

\footnotesize
\begin{frame}{Test Frame}

\begin{block}{Test Block}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[6]

\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the length of `\parindent` for text in such blocks at the same place you set the `\justifying`.  By default `beamer` has set this to `0pt`, but a usual amount would be `2em`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% For global Justification
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=0pt \rightskip=0pt plus 0cm}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying\setlength{\parindent}{2em}}


\begin{document}

\footnotesize
\begin{frame}{Test Frame}

\begin{block}{Test Block}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1): Thanks a lot @Andrew. Much appreciated.